# Elastic search to many aggregations: Unable to connect to the server

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet, elasticsearch-5, elastic-cloud

When I in Elastic Search 5.2.0 have more than 64 aggregations it fails with:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "message": "Unable to connect to the server."
}
```

This problem is related to Elastic Cloud - I have tested on a local elastic instance and it does not have this restriction.

Is this expected behavior?
I have tried removing different ones of the aggregations, but it all seems to come down to the number of aggregations. It works just fine with 65 or less aggregations.

It is simple aggregations like the following:

```
"aggs": {
    "wheelSize": {
      "filter": { ... },
      "aggs": {
        "facet_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "facets.wheelSize",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "tireSize": {
      "filter": { ... },
      "aggs": {
        "facet_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "facets.tireSize",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit:
**Code to replicate**:

Create index:

```
PUT product_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "prop1": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop2": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop3": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop4": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop5": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop6": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop7": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop8": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop9": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop10": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop11": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop12": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop13": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop14": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop15": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop16": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop17": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop18": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop19": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop20": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop21": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop22": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop23": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop24": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop25": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop26": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop27": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop28": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop29": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop30": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop31": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop32": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop33": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop34": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop35": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop36": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop37": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop38": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop39": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop40": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop41": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop42": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop43": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop44": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop45": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop46": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop47": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop48": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop49": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop50": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop51": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop52": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop53": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop54": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop55": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop56": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop57": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop58": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop59": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop60": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop61": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop62": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop63": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop64": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop65": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop66": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop67": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop68": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop69": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop70": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop71": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop72": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop73": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop74": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop75": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop76": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop77": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop78": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop79": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "prop80": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
"index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Search: (remove/add aggregation to see the problem)

```
GET product_test/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "prop1": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop1",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop2": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop2",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop3": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop3",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop4": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop4",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop5": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop5",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop6": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop6",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop7": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop7",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop8": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop8",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop9": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop9",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop10": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop10",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop11": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop11",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop12": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop12",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop13": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop13",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop14": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop14",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop15": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop15",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop16": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop16",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop17": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop17",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop18": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop18",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop19": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop19",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop20": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop20",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop21": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop21",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop22": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop22",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop23": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop23",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop24": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop24",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop25": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop25",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop26": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop26",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop27": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop27",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop28": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop28",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop29": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop29",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop30": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop30",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop31": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop31",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop32": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop32",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop33": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop33",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop34": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop34",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop35": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop35",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop36": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop36",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop37": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop37",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop38": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop38",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop39": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop39",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop40": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop40",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop41": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop41",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop42": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop42",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop43": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop43",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop44": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop44",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop45": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop45",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop46": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop46",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop47": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop47",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop48": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop48",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop49": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop49",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop50": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop50",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop51": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop51",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop52": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop52",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop53": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop53",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop54": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop54",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop55": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop55",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop56": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop56",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop57": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop57",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop58": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop58",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop59": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop59",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop60": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop60",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop61": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop61",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop62": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop62",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop63": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop63",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop64": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop64",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "prop65": {
      "filter": {},
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "prop65",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the problem was actually related the empty filter clause in some cases, because it created a warning for each aggragation.
And Elastic Cloud had a limit for 64 warnings - hence the error. (they are increasing that number now)

We fixed it by adding a match_all in the cases where it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the conditionless 'filter' aggregation on top of each 'terms' aggregation? If its not just for simplifying the exmaple than
It seems unnecessary. Maybe you should try remove those 'filter' aggs and put all of the 'terms' aggs as top level instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; 
instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the questioner.

Comment: It is just a simplification